# How to insert duplicate record in the same table with only change the date to the next date

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a requirement where I need to duplicate the present record with data column update to the next date.

I have table data like below:

```
cobdate     system  b_id    b_type  L_TYPE  lode    symbol
------------------------------------------------------------
20150205    M   N1  F   L   P   T
20150205    M   N1  F   L   P   E
20150205    M   N1  F   L   P   E
```

I want to insert the same data for the next day in the same table.
After insertion I want the data in the table to be like below:

```
cobdate     system  b_id    b_type  L_TYPE  lode    symbol
-------------------------------------------------------------
20150206    M   N1  F   L   P   T
20150206    M   N1  F   L   P   E
20150206    M   N1  F   L   P   E
```

Comment: IMHO You can done this with store procedure

Comment: yes . As per the design its a number column.

Comment: ok, you need to transform it to date to get the next date, then transform it back to number, as in my answer.

Comment: i am thinking  of a procedure ,in which i can pass the whole cobdate value for a update on cobdate column before transfer to the same table ..? not sure ..@sundar

Comment: This is not what you had asked. And is still unclear. If you want to update a the cobdate column just use an update statement.

Comment: @florin ,simple update statement will update the whole records not the one which newly inserted. i want something which insert the duplicate record with only update the date column for the newly inserted record .

Comment: do you need to insert new duplicate data or just want to increment the value alone?

Comment: I want to insert new duplicate data with cobdate updated to next date @ThiyaguATR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because cobdate is a number, you need to transform it to date, add one day(date operation), then tranform it back to number:

```
insert into table(
   cobdate, 
   system,b_id, b_type, L_TYPE, lode, symbol
   )
select 
   to_char(to_date(cobdate,'yyyymmdd')+1,'yyyymmdd'), 
   system,b_id, b_type, L_TYPE, lode, symbol
from table
where cobdate='20150205';
```

However, you should take note that dates should be stored as DATE, not numbers, not varchars, nor spreaded on three or more columns(ex year, month, day).

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory chiding: You should store dates as `DATE`s, not as `NUMBER`s. That said, to add one day to a date stored as a number should not be difficult:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ( cobdate, system, b_id, b_type, l_type, lode, symbol )
SELECT TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(cobdate, 'YYYYMMDD') + 1, 'YYYYMMDD' ) )
     , system, b_id, b_type, l_type, lode, symbol
  FROM mytable
 WHERE cobdate = 20150205;
```